# Javascript object factory method that passes arguments object as parameters

Tags: javascript

The following code does not work as desired ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v48ppq73/5/)):

```js
function makeFoo(a, b) {
  var foo = new Foo();
  Foo.apply(foo, arguments);
  return foo;
}
var Foo = function(a, b) {
  console.log(
    "This should be called once. "+
    "a=\"" + a + "\", " + 
    "b=\"" + b + "\", "
  );
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
}
Foo.prototype.go = function() {
  console.log("a: " + this.a);
  console.log("b: " + this.b);
};
var foo = makeFoo("Hello", "World");
foo.go();
```

Expected output:

> This should be called once. a="Hello", b="World"
>   a: Hello
>   b: World

Actual output:

> This should be called once. a="undefined", b="undefined"
>   This should be called once. a="Hello", b="World"
>   a: Hello
>   b: World

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/v48ppq73/6/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you call `Foo` twice: via `new` and via function call.

I think with `new Foo()` you only wanted to create an object which inherits from `Foo.prototype`. To achieve that, use `Object.create(Foo.prototype)` instead.

```js
function makeFoo(a, b) {
  var foo = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
  var result = Foo.apply(foo, arguments);
  return Object(result) === result ? result : foo;
}
var Foo = function(a, b) {
  console.log(
    "This should be called once. "+
    "a=\"" + a + "\", " + 
    "b=\"" + b + "\", "
  );
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
}
Foo.prototype.go = function() {
  console.log("a: " + this.a);
  console.log("b: " + this.b);
};
var foo = makeFoo("Hello", "World");
foo.go();
```

But that's just a hack, which you are required to use in ECMAScript 5 because there is no way to instantiate a constructor with an arbitrary number of arguments.

Constructors should be instantiated, not called as functions. In ECMAScript 6, you can do it with `Reflect.construct`.

```js
function makeFoo(a, b) {
  return Reflect.construct(Foo, arguments);
}
var Foo = function(a, b) {
  console.log(
    "This should be called once. "+
    "a=\"" + a + "\", " + 
    "b=\"" + b + "\", "
  );
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
}
Foo.prototype.go = function() {
  console.log("a: " + this.a);
  console.log("b: " + this.b);
};
var foo = makeFoo("Hello", "World");
foo.go();
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks.  Why is the first snippet a hack? What is the problem with using a constructor as a function to achieve this result? And why must the result of `apply ()` be checked?

Comment: @Jodes the check on the return value is to handle the fact that the constructor function *might* return some primitive value when not invoked via `new`. A constructor invocation via `new` will ignore such a return value, so that test ensures that the right thing is returned from the "makeFoo" function.

Comment: @Jodes The first one is a hack because it uses [[Call]] instead of [[Construct]]. As Pointy said, I check the value returned by the constructor to emulate what the `new` operator does.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function makeFoo(a, b){
  var foo = new Foo(a,b);
  return foo;
}
```

Comment: The point seems to be able to pass an arbitrary number of arguments.