# Purpose of passing a single argument to Object ()?

Tags: javascript

In an answer to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39044209/javascript-object-factory-method-that-passes-arguments-object-as-parameters?noredirect=1#comment65438363_39044209), what is the purpose of passing an argument to `Object`s constructor, using it as a function, as per the following code?

```
function makeFoo(a, b) {
    var foo = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
    var result = Foo.apply(foo, arguments);
    return Object(result) === result ? result : foo;
}
```

Comment: [It's in the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), for reference.

Comment: And, you know, [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-object-value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Object constructor returns its parameter if it's already an object. What your code is doing therefore is checking to see if the `result` value is an object.

In the context of that function from the other question, the goal is to deal with the fact that the "Foo" constructor might try to return a non-object (like a string or something) when invoked other than via `new`. When you call a constructor with `new`, then any non-object explicit return value is ignored, and the return value will be the constructed object.

So that last line of "makeFoo" checks to see whether the returned value is already an object. If it is, then the Object constructor will return the reference without creating a new object, so it will be `===` to the parameter ("result"). If it's not `===`, then that means the constructor did something weird, and so the constructed "foo" instance will be returned instead.

And note that the other question described this as a "hack".

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ha ha. This is one of those things I love about Stackoverflow. I can't imagine what sort of weird situation I'd have to be in to need to know this sort of arcana, but you really get familiar with the dark corners of the language (and anything else) answering such questions.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that if the goal is to emulate `new`, it's flawed, as returning `null` from a function called with `new` results in the object created by `new`, whereas in the quoted code if `Foo` returns `null` the result is a new object. (How's that for arcana? ;-) )

Comment: Yes good point. That's probably among the things Oriol was thinking while typing the word "hack". Oh, and nice to know about that Reflect API.